# JGraphT: Finding shortest path regardless of Edge Direction

Tags: java, shortest-path, jgrapht

I build the following graph A->B<-C using JGraphT as seen below:

```
    DirectedPseudograph<Node, Edge> graph = new DirectedPseudograph<>(Edge.class);
    DijkstraShortestPath<Node, Edge> shortestPath = new DijkstraShortestPath<Node, Edge>(graph);
    Node bn1 = new Node("1", "A", null);
    Node bn2 = new Node("2", "B", null);
    Node bn3 = new Node("3", "C", null);

    graph.addVertex(bn1);
    graph.addVertex(bn2);
    graph.addVertex(bn3);

    Edge edge1 = new Edge("PART_OF");
    Edge edge2 = new Edge("IS_A");
    graph.addEdge(bn1, bn2, edge1);
    graph.addEdge(bn3, bn2, edge2);
```

But whenever I try to call:

```
shortestPath.getPath(node1, node3);
```

I get an empty array meaning there is no connection. I understand this might have to do with the direction of the edges as A->B->C works fine. Is there any way to find the path regardless of the direction of the edges between A and C?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [AsUndirectedGraph](https://jgrapht.org/javadoc/org/jgrapht/graph/AsUndirectedGraph.html) class for that.

```
Graph<Node, Edge> graph = new DirectedPseudograph<>(Edge.class);
Node bn1 = new Node("1", "A", null);
Node bn2 = new Node("2", "B", null);
Node bn3 = new Node("3", "C", null);

graph.addVertex(bn1);
graph.addVertex(bn2);
graph.addVertex(bn3);

Edge edge1 = new Edge("PART_OF");
Edge edge2 = new Edge("IS_A");
graph.addEdge(bn1, bn2, edge1);
graph.addEdge(bn3, bn2, edge2);

Graph<Node, Edge> undirGraph=new AsUndirectedGraph<>(graph);
ShortestPathAlgorithm<Node, Edge> shortestPath = new DijkstraShortestPath<Node, Edge>(undirGraph);
```

Note: you might want to use a `SimpleDirectedGraph` as opposed to a `DirectedPseudograph` unless you really need multiple edges/self-loops.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Accepted it as it answers the posed question. Is there a way to do this and keeping the direction of the edges?

Comment: The original `graph` still has all the edge directions. `undirGraph` is an undirected view of the directed graph. `undirGraph` is backed by the original graph, so modifications to the original graph are automatically reflected in `undirGraph`.